# Как создать функцию, которая будет фильтровать данный массив

Tags: массивы, kotlin

Как создать функцию, которая потребует массив строк с двумя аргументами и строку в качестве ключа, которая будет фильтровать данный массив по переданному ключу аргумента (String), если элемент массива содержит не менее 3 символов переданного аргумента, будет отфильтрован, результат печати , если результата нет, необходимо вывести «нет результата» в виде текста.

**если элемент массива содержит не менее 3 символов переданного аргумента** ***Именно это строка никак не получается.Есть кто знает как можно сделать***

```
fun main() {
    val myArray = arrayOf("akaio","huise","seoli")
    val word = "aka"
   arrCheck(myArray,word)
 /*   arrFilter1(myArray,word)*/
}

//Simple way to check if array contains a word
fun arrCheck(arr: Array<String>, ex: String) {
    for (i in arr) {
        if (i.contains(ex)) {
            val filteredArray = arr.filterNot { it == ex }
            println(filteredArray)
        }else
            println("No Result")

    }
}
```

Comment: Разбейте аргумент на список символов и проверяйте каждый элемент массива на предмет того, сколько символов он содержит

Comment: И если допустим содержит 3 но разные буквы не совпадающие  @Alex_Skvortsov

Comment: Мне нужно проверить если совпадают но первые 3 три буквы

Comment: Что-то я не могу понять условие задачи. Вам нужно найти все слова в массиве, которые имеют такое же начало, как и переданный ключ, причем совпадающим начало считается, если совпадают первые три символа?

Comment: Да именно @ Alex_Skvortsov

Comment: Тогда просто замените `i.contains(ex)` на `i.length >=3 && i[0] == ex[0] && i[1] == ex[1] && i[2] == ex[2]`. Этот код подразумевает, что ключ `ex` содержит не менее 3 символов

Comment: Как то думал о током но с синтаксом были проблемы никак не смог Спасибо большое @ Alex_Skvortsov

Answer (score 0):

Если вам требуется среди списка слов найти все слова, в которых будут присутствовать абсолютно все буквы из искомого слова(включая не уникальные вхождения), то можно сделать как-то так:

```
val found = arr.filter { word ->
    val startIndexes = mutableMapOf<Char, Int>()
    !ex.any() { c ->
        startIndexes[c] = word.indexOf(c, startIndexes.getOrDefault(c, -1)+1)
        startIndexes[c] == -1
    }
}

println(if (found.isNotEmpty()) found else "Not found")
```

Если же нужно найти строки длинной больше 3 символов, у которых начало совпадает с первыми 3-мя символами переданного слова, то все проще:

```
val found = arr.filter { it.length > 3 && it.startsWith(ex.substring(0, 3)) }
```